# Удаление альфа канала в изображении

Tags: c#

Делаю кроппинг картинки. Как удалить альфа-канал в изображении?

```
public Bitmap cropAtRect(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
{
    Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);

    return nb;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618259/remove-transparency-in-images-with-c-sharp) советуют нарисовать белый квадрат и поверх него нарисовать свое изображение:

```
void RemTransp(string file) {
    Bitmap src = new Bitmap(file);
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(src.Size.Width,src.Size.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target);
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.White)), 0, 0, target.Width, target.Height);
    g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0);
    target.Save("Your target path");
}
```

Comment: Как это поможет ТСу отрезать тот пустой кусок?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте конструктор `new Bitmap(Int32, Int32, PixelFormat)`, где из перечисления PixelFormat выберите те, что без Alpha-канала, например `Format24bppRgb`